# Ideas on false positives of schema compare

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I have a SQL Data project. When I compare it with my dev database, it is returning a bunch of false positives. They are all functions (but not all the functions, just some of them). I can see no difference. I've done diffs of the source shown in the compare window (copy paste into UltraEdit). I've diffed the source file with the script produced by the server. I've tried messing with the encoding. I've checked the EOLs. In ALL cases, there are no differences to be found (the compare tool shows no differences either...i.e. while the function is marked as being different, no differences actually show in the object definitions area).

Any ideas on what is causing this and how I can clear it up?

Comment: Check columns like `uses_ansi_nulls`, `uses_quoted_identifier` etc. in `sys.sql_modules`.

Comment: None of the functions that are causing problems are referenced in this table. :(

Comment: Functions are absolutely stored in sys.sql_modules, maybe you're just not looking in the right database. To identify them by name, you need to join with sys.objects on object_id.

Comment: When you gen up the script and run it against the server for even one of the functions does it stop showing up in the diff report?

Comment: Peter, the answer is that for some functions, everything is OK. But the ones returning false positives, they are very consistent. I've tried updating the db from the model and the model from the db. Never any visible differences and always reported as different.

Comment: Aaron, yep, I was looking in the wrong place. I compared a function that is working and one that is returning a false positive and all the fields in sys.sql_modules (except object_id and definition) are the same. :(

Comment: fwiw I have seen the same behaviour, and executing the script does not make the false positive go away. I Think the code that does the script gen and the one making the compare are not synched. I have not made char by char comparisons of the scripts though.

Comment: i'm facing the same issue. two of my functions always show up as different when no visible difference is found. SQL Server 2019 Express Edition, VS 2019 Community Edition

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. When I apply the DB to the project, they remain false positives.

However when I apply the project to the DB, the false positives go away.

So, to clear it up, compare the project to the DB, and Update the DB from the project for the troublesome objects.